# Groupby and if condtion on a data frame in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a below data frame

```
      df=
         city    code     qty1   qty2  month    type
         hyd     1        10     12       1      x 
         hyd     2        12     21              y
         hyd     2        15     36              x 
         hyd     4        25     44       3      z     
         pune    1        10     1               x
         pune    3        12     2        2      y
         pune    1        15     3               x   
         pune    2        25     4               x
         ban     2        10     1        1      X       
         ban     4        10     2               x  
         ban     2        12     3               x
         ban     1        15     4        3      y
```

I want to groupby(city and code) and find both res1 and res2 based on the below conditions.

The result data frame is

```
result=  
     city    code     res1     res2  
     hyd     1        Nan       12      
     hyd     2        27        Nan
     hyd     4        Nan       Nan     
     pune    1        25        Nan
     pune    3        Nan       Nan
     pune    2        25        Nan
     ban     2        12        10  
     ban     4        10        Nan
     ban     1        Nan       Nan
```

I have tried grouping and itering the result of groupyby with the conditions. But no result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "I have tried grouping and itering the result of groupyby with the conditions. ": please show us your attempt.

Comment: Why have you dropped some rows in your expected output? e.g. you had 4 rows in city hyd initially, and only 3 in expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` then calculated what you need one by one , then `concat` back

```
g=df.groupby(['city','code'])
pd.concat([g.apply(lambda x : sum(x['qty1'][x['month']==''])),g.apply(lambda x : sum(x['qty2'][(x['month']!='')&(x['type']=='x')]))],axis=1)
Out[135]: 
            0   1
city code        
ban  1      0   0
     2     12   0
     4     10   0
hyd  1      0  12
     2     27   0
     4      0   0
pune 1     25   0
     2     25   0
     3      0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df = df.set_index(['city', 'code'])

cond1 = df.month.isnull()
df['res1'] = df[cond1].groupby(['city', 'code']).qty1.sum()

cond2 = df.month.notnull() & (df.type=='x')
df['res2'] = df[cond2].groupby(['city', 'code']).qty2.sum()


             qty1   qty2    month   type    res1    res2
city    code                        
hyd     1    10     12      1.0     x       NaN     12.0
        2    12     21      NaN     y       27.0    NaN
        2    15     36      NaN     x       27.0    NaN
        4    25     44      3.0     z       NaN     NaN
pune    1    10     1       NaN     x       25.0    NaN
        3    12     2       2.0     y       NaN     NaN
        1    15     3       NaN     x       25.0    NaN
        2    25     4       NaN     x       25.0    NaN
ban     2    10     1       1.0     x       12.0    1.0
        4    10     2       NaN     x       10.0    NaN
        2    12     3       NaN     x       12.0    1.0
        1    15     4       3.0     y       NaN     NaN
```